# How to achieve Sencha Ext JS Grid's "Grouped Header" in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: jquery, extjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to achieve Sencha ExtJS Grid's "Grouped Header" in Kendo UI Grid. Below is an example of the "Grouped Header": 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#grouped-header-grid

In the example, "Stock Price" grouped header straddles across "Price", "Change" and "% Change" (sub) columns. How do I achieve the same thing in Kendo UI Grid?

Having read the documentation and examples carefully, the only thing I seem to be able to find is Kendo UI Grid's "Groupable" functionality. Obviously this is not what I'm after. Hopefully I've missed something in my research.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this "Grouped Header" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Kendo UI grid doesn't support this feature. Part of our plans though.

Comment: Ok, thank you for letting me know. Is there an ETA? I might have to use Ext JS in the mean time.

Comment: No hard ETA. Probably some time next year (hopefully the first half). There are hacks with injecting HTML in the grid header but I won't recommend them.

Comment: I'm beginning to realize I need this more and more :P Will be fantastic when it appears as a feature.